# How to add lib into modules in wildfly 8.2 Final?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my jar using appclient but i get this error.

This is my deploy command

```
C:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin>appclient socket-gateway.jar
```

> 16:56:03,155 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-16) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."socket-gateway.jar".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."socket-gateway.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733:
>   Failed to process phase POST_MODULE ofdeployment "socket-gateway.jar"
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014187: Could not load view
>   com.switching.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbRefProcessor.processDescriptorEntries(EjbRefProcessor.java:99)
>           at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.java:95)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>           ... 5 more **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote from [Module
>   "deployment.socket-gateway.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]**
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbRefProcessor.processDescriptorEntries(EjbRefProcessor.java:97)
>           ... 7 more
>
> 16:56:03,167 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Thread-43) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address:
>   ([("deployment" => "socket-gate way.jar")]) - failure description:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"socket-gateway.jar\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.Start Exception in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"socket-gateway.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733:
>   Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
>   \"socket-gateway.jar\" Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   JBAS014187: Could not load view
>   com.switching.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.switching.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote from [Module
>   \"deployment.socket-gateway.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
>   16:56:03,170 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-43) JBAS015870:
>   Deploy of deployment "socket-gateway.jar" was rolled back with the
>   following failure message: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"socket-gateway.jar\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployme
>   nt.unit.\"socket-gateway.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to
>   process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"socket-gateway.jar\" Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014187: Could not load view
>   com.switching.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.switching.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote from [Module
>   \"deployment.socket-gateway.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
>   16:56:03,197 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread
>   1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment socket-gateway.jar (runtime-name:
>   socket-gateway.jar ) in 26ms 16:56:03,198 INFO
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (Thread-43) JBAS014774: Service status
>   report JBAS014777: Services which failed to start: service
>   jboss.deployment.unit ."socket-gateway.jar".POST_MODULE

From that error it clearly said " java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote from [Module "deployment.socket-gateway.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]".

And i already read the [redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Migration_Guide/Find_the_JBoss_Module_Dependency1.html)

using that references , i make folder in "C:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\com\switching\serverapi" and put the serverapi.jar (this jar where the code for com.serverapi.ServiceManagerBeanRemote )

but i still have same problems. Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever come around to this?

Answer (score 0):

i think the folder you have made is not in the right directory. It should be under:
[WidlFly-HOME]\modules\system\layers\base .. \com\switching\serverapi\serverapi.jar